# Mediatr Polymorphic dispatch of request handler not working

Tags: mediatr, dryioc

I have a Mediatr request handler that I want to take one of two different (related) requests. When I use the basic request it works fine, but when I use the `PermissionedGetInformationRequest`, I get an error indicating it can't find the handler for my request.

> Error constructing handler for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler2[PermissionedGetInformationRequest, DataIWantView]. Register your handlers with the container

I'm not sure if I just haven't configured my IoC container properly, or the container doesn't support what I'm trying to do, or if I'm trying to do something that isn't supported by Mediatr (but I'm pretty sure it is, I seem to remember we had some similar code that worked ok using our old IoC, StructureMap)

I have a request:

```
public class GetInformationRequest : IRequest<DataIWantView>
{
}
```

and a request which is inherited from that

```
public class PermissionedGetInformationRequest : GetInformationRequest  
{
    public int RequesterId { get;set; }
}
```

and a request handler:

```
public class GetInformationHandler : IRequestHandler<GetInformationRequest, DataIWantView>
{
    public Task<DataIWantView> Handle(GetInformationRequestrequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request is PermissionedGetInformationRequest permissionedRequest)
        {
            // Check permission
        }

        // Get the data I want
    }
}
```

I use dryioc as my IoC container, and to register my handlers I use

```
container.RegisterMany(new[] { typeof(GetInformationHandler).Assembly }, Registrator.Interfaces, made: PropertiesAndFields.Auto);
```

Comment: Seems like the problem is in DryIoc. 
Could you try to resolve `IRequestHandler<PermissionedGetInformationRequest, DataIWantView>` directly? And after that try to resolve the array of `IRequestHandler<PermissionedGetInformationRequest, DataIWantView>[]`?

Comment: DryIoc v4.6 is released just now with the `Rules.WithVariantGenericTypesInResolve()`. Try it and see if the error disappears.

Comment: @dadhi Thanks, I have tried upgrading to 4.6 and added `Rules.WithVariantGenericTypesInResolve()` to the container, but am still unable to resolve the type. trying to resolve `IRequestHandler<PermissionedGetInformationRequest, DataIWantView>` just throws an error "No service for type", trying to resolve an array of handlers just comes back as an empty array

Comment: Then this is something different. I would suggest opening the issue in MediatR and/or in DryIoc repos with minified failing test.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved by using `Rules.WithVariantGenericTypesInResolve()`. Despite my original comment above, I just wasn't setting the rules on the container correctly. Once I set the rule, it worked perfectly.